# In Domino Designer I want an interactive commenting section

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

In Domino Designer I have a form and want an interactive commenting section putting onto it, where it will basically look just like a blog on the internet, but this is to go onto a form that will sit on a database. Any recommendations? I don't want a table, I would like something a bit more interactive than that.

Comment: Have you looked at using https://disqus.com/

Comment: The way that's more traditional for long-time Lotus Notes users would be done using response documents. These can be shown in an embedded view, which is a bit clunky looking but still very familar to Notes users, or through a dynamic table as described by Karl-Henry. Techniques that don't rely on response documents can be tricky, because the summary data limit can be a problem for you if you're not careful. It's also probably not possible to have both editable comments and rich text in comments simultaneously unless you use response documents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the technique I am describing here: 
http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

Just create a button that will create a new comment document and then refresh the main form. I use this in a bunch of my applications.